# Using javascript to remove link formatting on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using javascript (and jQuery) to move between three box descriptions.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#foo-box').show();
        $('#bar-box').hide();
        $('#bob-box').hide();

      $('#bar-link').click(function() {
        $('#foo-box').hide();
        $('#bob-box').hide();
        $('#bar-box').show();
         return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

**html**

```
<div id="stuff">
    <a href="" id="foo-link">Foo</a>
    <a href="" id="bar-link">Bar</a>
    <a href="" id="bob-link">Bob</a>
    <div id="foo-box">Hello</div>
    <div id="bar-box">World</div>
    <div id="bob-box">!!!</div>
</div>
```

But after clicking on a link I want it to be normal text. I can't seem to figure out a good, elegant way of doing this in javascript (I've found a few ways that may work, but are basically hacks).

Am I just being thick?

Comment: if you mean the coloring of the link - a:visited { text-decoation: none }

Comment: you mean you want to remove the link after clicking

Comment: Yes, it's not clear to what 'normal text' related to

Comment: typo - you mean `text-decoration`

Comment: I'm thinking it might be about functionality of the links rather than the looks of them. It's not like you have to use `<a>` tags to do this anyways.

Comment: Oops sorry, I was a bit ambiguous. I wanted to remove the link entirely, rather than use a styling option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe jquery `replaceWith()` would help?

```
  $('#bar-link').click(function() {
    ...
     $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
     return false;
  });
```

Comment: This literally replaces the link with plain text, as per the OP request. If you just want it to *appear* as normal text, do a styling tweak a la @DrStrangeLove's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bar-link').click(function() {
        $('#foo-box').hide();
        $('#bob-box').hide();
        $('#bar-box').show();
        $(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');
         return false;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("visited");
}

.visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```